# Mysterious Apache is running without me finding it

Tags: windows, apache

So i've been messing around with different server packages such as wamp, zend serv, etc. And Now I have unistalled all THOSE, well so I thought at least. Installed a new copy of Wamp, but I can't start it, it says that I already have an Apache started - How can I find it??

(And I can as well browse localhost:80) without problems, but it's not my fresh Wamp..

I used netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80 in cmd to find what PID its listening, and it was 5912, however I can't find a processor having that PID.

What the hell is going on?

Comment: Have you tried using Process Explorer, from sysinternals ? It might be a great help for you.

Comment: You've been taken by the apache daemon :p, but srsly it's probably still a running process, crappy uninstallers missed it. Check in your task manager for the httpd process and end it's life.

Comment: tasklist /v /FI "PID eq 5912"      or simply kill it taskkill /F /PID 5912

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the service messing with me!